# Is asking about reverting phone to Android on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

A device once had a mobile derivative of Ubuntu, but OP wants to revert to Android OS...is this on-topic or belong somewhere like generic linux or android enthusiasts?

Case study [How to return to stock Android after installing Ubuntu Touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211987/cant-return-to-stock-android)

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, he flashed the phone from Android to Ubuntu and wishes to go back. Most of the time it's a tough call but I know the Ubuntu Touch team watches their respective tags and we "support" to an extent flashing from Android to Touch then back to Android.

Also, that question is answered and marked as answered over a year ago. We're not going to close old questions "just because" it breaks a policy especially if it's got an accepted answer.

Comment: How is it then that [removing ubuntu and putting windows back on](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) is on-topic?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong question. These questions are rather simple to answer  (once) or **link to a duplicate**.

The tricky part may be certain specific devices, in these cases the answer should be that the device is (obviously) not supported by Ubuntu Phone/Touch and therefore not here.

From the Android Enthusiasts perspective I wouldn't want the question there, because I wouldn't know what the Ubuntu Tools did to the device (like installing a custom recovery image).

If possible, treat it like a blank device where you want to install a certain operating system.

- Officially **supported** Ubuntu Phone devices

  - Answer here, link to duplicate or [instructions on the Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Restoring_Android).
- **Not supported** devices:

  - Answer with link to generic guide that gives instructions how to reflash (non-locked) Android devices and a comment that the device is not supported on Ubuntu.
  - [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/20651) would possibly be a good starting point.

And possibly link all duplicates to these two questions.

Comment: "Instead of moving questions around like acting with corporate irresponsibility, one should answer the question." : are you suggesting we should answer questions even if they're off topic?

Comment: @terdon I'm suggesting to differentiate between supported and unsupported devices and have answers for those two cases. One links and cites instructions on the wiki (I'm sure we already have that), the other links to an appropriate answer that deals with custom ROMs (because that's what these are and if you can flash one you can flash to others too). All the **others are duplicates** of the former two. So at best these are two crisp answers that we should already have, just need to find and review them. Link to the rest. That couldn't possibly be so much effort, like you make it sound.

Comment: I just don't understand what _corporate irresponsibility_ is in this context (it sounds kinda like a rant) and you seem to be implying that questions should be answered even if they are off topic. If that's not what you're saying, please edit and clarify. "Moving a question around" is often the right thing to do.

Comment: @terdon That was probably superfluous. I removed that part, is it clearer now what I mean? From my experience, moving monolithic things around instead of spending a little effort into breaking them up into individual components is even better for the OP, because he gets quicker feedback (and probably part of the solution) instead of different people wasting his time by throwing it around (happens sometimes in professional support teams), because they don't understand the *whole* thing. We know Ubuntu, we (part of us) support Ubuntu phone, we link to the rest (that is about custom ROMs).

Comment: Ah much better, thanks, have a +1.